# HTML call PHP function on Submit without leaving the page

Tags: php, html, post

Hello Everyone

I am trying to make some of my php scripts reusable by saving them in a separate file on the server.

/public_html/scripts/phpfunctions.php

```
<?php echo 'This function has been called' ?>
```

And I have my HTML form

```
<form action="scripts/phpfunctions.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user_input">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now that the function is a separate file it navigates the browser to that file instead of executing the script in my current file.

Normally I would solve this with AJAX and call the php function instead of a php page.

Is it possible to call a php function from inside a php script after pressing the submit button (the way it would normally execute in a page like the one below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>No Title</title></head>
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       echo 'function has been called'
    }
?>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="user_input">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just require the file?

Comment: the script will have database connection details, is not insecure to include/require the php file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> HTML call PHP function on Submit without leaving the page

Yes, just don't use `action` and the form will be submitted to the current page.

```
<form method="POST">
    <!-- your input tags -->
</form>
```

To call a PHP function, check if it is submitted, then call the function

```
if(isset($_POST['user_input'])){
   myFunction(); //here goes the function call
}
```

> Is it possible to call a php function from inside a php script after pressing the submit button (the way it would normally execute in a page like the one below)?

No, because the submit button is an HTML element and when you click on it, you will need JavaScript (e.g. via Ajax) to send it to the server (PHP) and then the PHP page on the server can execute the function needed.

You may use something like `<form method="POST" onsubmit="myJSFunction()">`. The  JavaScript function `myJSFunction()` is called when you click on the submit button, using this function you may send the required data to the server (e.g. via ajax) and execute your PHP function there on the server.

Comment: This did not work for me, it still took me to www.mywebsite.com/myfile.php (blank page)

Answer (score 1):

Use javascipt onclick="function()" and leave the form action empty. The function will be performed on the client side but the html CAN be modified

```
<button type="submit" onclick="action()">Submit</button>

<script>
     function action() {
         //Your code here
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you include an example? this is sounding a bit ajaxy to me